# Mysql Subpartioning --Partition by day and then a value

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have a table on a Linux Mysql server running 5.5.24 that looks like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE Level (
      snr float DEFAULT NULL,
      checkDate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      checkTs int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      CheckType tinyint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      UNIQUE KEY LevelIndex (checkDate,snr),
      KEY checkDateIndex (checkDate),
      KEY CheckTypeDate (checkTs,CheckType)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5290273472 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

it has roughly 400 million rows - i want to take it and partition it, first by single day, then by the Value of CheckType (which is either 0,1,2,3). Or, at least, I think i do - that's what brought me here - what i am asking is, is what i explained possible, and then secondly, if it is, is it a sound idea? I am trying to make it so reports that look at a single day are quick for each check type, but i have the historical data for, say, 30 days worth of data available to take a look at still. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Hi, can you show sample data you want for your 2 reports? So we can visualize it better

Comment: heh just learning how to use this site -  i posted the data in an answer instead of as a comment, below

Answer (score 0):

select snr,checkDate,CheckType from dbGreen.Level where checkDate >= '2012-10-14' and checkDate < '2012-10-15';
produces daily report

```
+------+---------------------+----------------+
| snr  | checkDate           |   CheckType    |
+------+---------------------+----------------+
|   38 | 2012-10-14 19:33:01 |              2 |
| 37.9 | 2012-10-14 19:33:01 |              1 |
| 44.9 | 2012-10-14 19:33:01 |              2 |
| 35.6 | 2012-10-14 19:33:01 |              2 |
| 37.3 | 2012-10-14 19:33:01 |              2 |
| 37.6 | 2012-10-14 19:33:01 |              2 |
| 37.5 | 2012-10-14 19:33:01 |              2 |
| 37.8 | 2012-10-14 19:33:01 |              1 |
| 35.8 | 2012-10-14 19:33:01 |              1 |
| 39.6 | 2012-10-14 19:33:01 |              2 |
```